# Multiple column categories in MS Excel pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

Is it possible to design a pivot table in such a way that I have multiple column categories? Please see examples below:

```
|Group  |      Category 1     |      Category 2     |
|       | good |  bad | total | good |  bad | total |
|---------------------------------------------------|
|Group 1|  40% |  60% |  100% |  60% |  40% |  100% |
|Group 2|  30% |  70% |  100% |  20% |  80% |  100% |
...
```

I can get the Category 1 part or the Category 2 part, but not both. If you put both as my column input, I get the combined version (i.e. good/good, good/bad, bad/good, and bad/bad).

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is possible - see the attached image:

[pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mciGw.png)